# Class member value overwritten by previous member

Tags: c++, class, c++11, memory-management

If I create a two class members of `char*` type and is array. And if I resize first member of the class it overwrite the second member with same values.
Why it happens?
Is it some memory management issues?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    private:
        const char *arr1[0];
        const char *arr2[4] {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four"
        };
    public:
        void run() {
            int f = 0;

            *this->arr1 = new char[4];

            for(f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
                this->arr1[f] = "foo";
            }

            for(f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
                cout << this->arr2[f] << endl;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    myclass *my = new myclass();
    my->run();

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Comment: actually, char *arr[] is not of type char * but char **

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<const char*>` instead of C style arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const char *arr1[0];
```

Zero-sized arrays are not allowed in standard C++. Your compiler is allowing it as an extension to the language.

Even if your compiler has this extension, dereferencing an array of size `0` causes undefined behavior and you are doing this here:

```
*this->arr1 = new char[4];
```

---

I don't know what your intention here is, either you want

```
const char *arr1[4];
```

in which case `*this->arr1 = new char[4];` is unnecessary or you want

```
const char **arr1;
```

in which case it should be `this->arr1 = new const char*[4];`.

---

You should not use `char*` to manage strings, use `std::string` instead, which does the memory management for you. Similarly, for multiple strings use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char**`.

---

There doesn't seem any reason to use dynamic memory allocation in `main` either. The same way as you should use `std::vector` to manage dynamically-sized arrays of objects instead of using `new[]`/`delete[]`, don't use dynamic memory allocation to create single objects if you don't have a good reason for it and if you have to, use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw `new`/`delete`.

```
int main()
{
    myclass my;
    my.run();

    return 0;
}
```

This does the same without dynamic allocation.